# My shell script stops after exec

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a shell script that looks like this:

```
 for i in $ACTIONS_DIR/*
    do
            if [ -x $i ]; then
                    exec $i nap
            fi
    done
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to list every file in $ACTIONS_DIR to be able to execute it. Each file under $ACTIONS_DIR is another shell script.

Now, the problem here is that after using exec the script stops and doesn't go to the next file in line. Any ideas why might this be?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795129/no-code-will-run-after-exec-in-bash-script/60795170#60795170

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`exec` replaces the shell process. Remove it if you only want to call the command as a subprocess instead.

Answer (score 8):

`exec` transfers control of the PID over to the program you're exec'ing. This is mainly used in scripts whose sole purpose is to set up options to that program. Once the `exec` is hit, nothing below it in the script is executed.

Also, you should try some quoting techniques:

```
for i in "$ACTIONS_DIR"/*
    do
        if [ -x "$i" ]; then
                "./$i" nap
        fi
done
```

You might also look into using `find` for this operation:

```
find "$ACTIONS_DIR" \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -type f \
    -perm +0111 \
    -exec {} nap \;
```

Comment: `for i in "$ACTIONS_DIR"/*` would be a bit safer if we don't know the directory name not to contain whitespace (or if we don't know/control the value of `IFS`).

Answer (score 2):

exec never returns to the caller. Just try

```
if [ -x "${i}" ]
then
    "${i}" nap
fi
```

Comment: `"$i"`, or you'll have misbehavior if the program name contains whitespace.