# Issue running multiple shell scripts inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, centos7

I am trying to create a shell script that runs several scripts under CentOS 7. Each script starts with `#!/bin/bash`. Each script is tested and can be run as a standalone shell script with no problem.

***Content of scripts_all.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sudo yum install g++ make binutils cmake openssl-devel boost-devel zlib-devel
sh script_1.sh # executes all the contents of script_1.sh
sh script_2.sh # does not executed any of the command in script_2.sh. 
sh script_3.sh
sh script_4.sh
```

**script_1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-9-gcc*
scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
which gcc
gcc --version
```

**script_2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum install centos-release-scl-rh
sudo yum-config-manager --enable centos-release-scl-rh
sudo yum install devtoolset-9
scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
```

It appears that `./scripts_all.sh` will successfully execute `set -x`, `sudo yum`, `sh script_1.sh` but stops at `sh script_2.sh`. It is worth noting that I can run `sh script_2.sh` with no issue independent of `scripts_all.sh`. I don't know why the rest of the scripts won't be run.

`./scripts_all.sh` prints the lines of `sh script_1.sh` and their executions but it never prints the lines of `sh script_2.sh`.

Could someone kindly help?

Comment: If they're bash scripts you should use `bash script_N.sh`. Or if they begin with `#!` just use `./script_N.sh`

Comment: I tried `./script_N.sh` and still the same issue.

Comment: Does `set -x` display the `script_1.sh` line?

Comment: If not, it means that `sudo yum ...` hasn't finished.

Comment: @Barmar yes it does print the lines of `script_1.sh`.

Comment: Why does it print those lines? Does that script also begin with `set -x`? Do the other scripts have that?

Comment: What does "stops at" mean? Does it hang forever, or does it [suddenly exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815151/why-does-my-script-suddenly-exit-after-a-command)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], to much information is missing to continue helping IMHO.

Comment: @Nic3500 please see the updated post.

Comment: Change the `sh script_1.sh` etc lines to `bash -x script_1.sh` (or `sh -x script_1.sh` since the scripts don't seem to use any Bash-specific syntax) and monitor what's going on.  Do you see the version information from `gcc --version` in `script_1.sh`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `gcc --version` is only printed when I comment out `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash`. I ran `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash` and it does not output anything to the screen.

Comment: That suggests the `scl` command is not completing.  Maybe it is waiting for input from the terminal.  Do you see the output from `which gcc` when you include the `scl` command?  If not, then it is close to certain that `scl` is trying to read from the terminal.  I dunno what — it isn't a command I'm familiar with.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is not waiting for any input. After execution, it brings the prompt again when I run it by itself.

Comment: If you're not seeing the `which gcc` and `gcc --version` output, then it is probable that the `scl` command is not completing, IMO.  What does the `bash` at the end of the command options do?  Does it run a `bash` process?  If so, where is its input coming from?  Running with the `-x` option (`sh -x script_1.sh`) would show you what is being executed, and whether `scl` is completing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `scl enable foo bar bash` actually runs bash instance with foo and bar Software Collections enabled. https://linux.die.net/man/1/scl

Comment: OK; and what is that `bash` instance doing?  Is it not waiting for input before it executes anything?  It's a little surprising that there isn't a prompt, but not completely astonishing.  Have you tried typing `exit` when `scl` hangs?

Comment: I just tried `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash & echo "Enabing devtoolset-9"` and it works and ultimately prints out the `gcc --version`.

Comment: Well, that `&` runs the `scl` command in background, leaving the `echo` to run, and then `which gcc` and `gcc --version`.  Replace the `&` with a semicolon.  Or replace the `&` with `-c 'echo Hi'` and a semicolon and see what happens.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Wonderful! Adding `-c echo "Hi"` made it work!

Comment: So that `bash` command specified at the end of `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash` was waiting for input from you, which is why it didn't terminate, and so on.  You've got the same issue at the end of `script_2.sh` — what about the other scripts?  But you now know what's going on and can decide what to do about it.  `-c exit` would simply terminate the shell (instead of echoing `Hi`), for example.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you would like to post a solution, I will accept it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Copying comments into the semblance of an answer.*</sup>

Change the `sh script_1.sh` etc lines to `bash -x script_1.sh` (or `sh -x script_1.sh` since the scripts don't seem to use any Bash-specific syntax) and monitor what's going on. Do you see the version information from `gcc --version` in `script_1.sh`?

> `gcc --version` is only printed when I comment out `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash`. I ran `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash` and it does not output anything to the screen.

That suggests the `scl` command is not completing. Maybe it is waiting for input from the terminal. Do you see the output from `which gcc` when you include the `scl` command? If not, then it is close to certain that `scl` is trying to read from the terminal. I dunno what it's reading — it isn't a command I'm familiar with.

> It is not waiting for any input. After execution, it brings the prompt again when I run it by itself.

If you're not seeing the `which gcc` and `gcc --version` output, then it is probable that the `scl` command is not completing, IMO. What does the `bash` at the end of the command options do? Does it run a `bash` process? If so, where is its input coming from? Running with the `-x` option (`sh -x script_1.sh`) would show you what is being executed, and whether `scl` is completing.

> `scl enable foo bar bash` actually runs a bash instance with `foo` and `bar` Software Collections enabled. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/scl

OK; and what is that `bash` instance doing? Is it not waiting for input before it executes anything? It's a little surprising that there isn't a prompt, but not completely astonishing. Have you tried typing `exit` when `scl` hangs?

> I just tried `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash & echo "Enabling devtoolset-9"` and it works and ultimately prints out the `gcc --version`.

Well, that `&` runs the `scl` command in background, leaving the `echo` to run, and then `which gcc` and `gcc --version`. Replace the `&` with a semicolon. Or replace the `&` with `-c 'echo Hi'` and a semicolon and see what happens.

> Wonderful! Adding `-c echo "Hi"` made it work!

So that `bash` command specified at the end of `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash` was waiting for input from you, which is why it didn't terminate (and you don't see `which gcc` running) and so on. You've got the same issue at the end of `script_2.sh` — what about the other scripts? But you now know what's going on and can decide what to do about it. Using `-c exit` would simply terminate the shell (instead of echoing `Hi`), for example.

I'd need to study the `scl` command more, but do you actually need to use it in these scripts?